# Url language prefix with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, url-rewriting

I'm lost in the url rewriting of Zend Framework !
I have a `route.ini` like that :

```
routes.page.route = :slug
```

and I have a call in the bootstrap like that :

```
protected function _initRoutes() {

    $uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if (!in_array('admin', $uri)) {
        //$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini');
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $router->addConfig($config, 'routes');

        $front->registerPlugin(new Rez_Controller_Plugin_Routing(), 2);
    }
}
```

the plugin is like that:

```
class Rez_Controller_Plugin_Routing extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) 
{
    $item_db = new Application_Model_DbTable_Item();

    if(NULL != $request->getParam("slug")){

        if("admin" == $request->getParam("slug")){

            $request->setModuleName('admin');
            $request->setControllerName("index");
            $request->setActionName('index');

        }

        $page = $item_db->getPage($request->getParam("slug"));

        if(FALSE == $page){

            $request->setModuleName('default');
            $request->setControllerName($request->getParam("slug"));
            $request->setActionName('index');

            return;

        }else{

           if(NULL !== $request->getParam("language")){
             $page["lang"] = $request->getParam("language");
           }

            $request->setModuleName('default');
            $request->setControllerName("index");
            $request->setActionName('page');
            $request->setParams($page);

            return;

        }

    }
}
```

the problem is that I have to prepend a language prefix in URL `"htttp://mywebsite.com/en/a-simple-page"` only when the language of the browser is English or when the user have clicked the English flag, otherwise, the URL have to be like `"http://mywebsite.com/a-simple-page"`.

I tried to add this in route.ini :

```
routes.page.route = :language/:slug
routes.page.reqs.language = "^(en|nl)$"
routes.page.defaults.language = "nl"
```

but when I tried `"http://mywebsite.com/a-simple-page"` it doesn't work while `"http://mywebsite.com/en/a-simple-page"` worked and I can get the param in the plugin. How to make it accept all URL even when a language code is not in the URL?

Comment: i manage to resolve my problem by adding more routes in route.ini

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not detect the user language with PHP then use sessions to store it? Display a little flag option at the top of the site e.g. http://www.graphicz.co.uk/en/

Detect language: http://www.dyeager.org/blog/2008/10/getting-browser-default-language-php.html

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you will need to chain 2 routes.

```
resources.router.routes.defaultmodule.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module
resources.router.routes.defaultmodule.abstract = On    
resources.router.routes.defaultmodule.defaults.module = "default"

resources.router.routes.locale.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route
resources.router.routes.locale.route = ":locale"
resources.router.routes.locale.reqs.locale = "^(en)$"
resources.router.routes.locale.defaults.locale = "nl"

resources.router.routes.default.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain
resources.router.routes.default.chain = "locale,defaultmodule"
```

Keep in mind that having same content under 2 urls is not good due to SEO implications. A redirect would be more appropriate.

Comment: the two url doesn't have the same content, there is one with the English and the ohter in Dutch.

Comment: Please have a look at my improved answer. I hope that helps.